# Hide component when clicking outside

Tags: react-native

I want to hide a component when clicked outside it. Something like dismissing keyboard. I have done this by wrapping my whole view inside ToucheableWithoutFeedback by changing state onPress but Toucheables disables ScrollView.

Can you give me an idea of a way that scrollview still works?

or

How can I handle taps in views or outside my component??

my current code is something like this:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() =>{this.setState({toggle:false})}}>
  <View>
    {//content}
  </View>

  <ScrollView>
    {//lists here}
  </ScrollView>
  {{
  if(this.state.toggle){
   return 
     (<View>
      {//The view that im hiding when clicking outside it}
     </View>)
  }
  else
   return <View/>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Comment: I know it's long gone since you asked this question. Putting this link here for future devs asking the same question as you. [How to detect click outside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60478348/1903781). The approach uses internal React private props due to lack of alternatives

Answer (score 7):

The easy way is with a modal transparent

```
<Modal
          transparent
          visible={this.state.isAndroidShareOpen}
          animationType="fade"
          onRequestClose={() => {}}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={1}
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({
                isAndroidShareOpen: false,
              });
            }}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              flex: 1,
            }}
          >
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={1}
              style={{
                backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
                left: 0,
                top: 50,
                aspectRatio: 1.5,
                width,
                position: 'absolute',
              }}
            >
                <Text>content</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Modal>
```

Answer (score 5):

One approach is to have "fake" container for `TouchableWithoutFeedback` whis is just a layer below the actual content. Here's an example: https://rnplay.org/apps/k2RSNw

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={(evt) => this.toggleState(evt)}>
        <View style={styles.touchable}></View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <View style={[styles.modal, this.isModalVisible()]}>
        <Text>Modal</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

If you want to do something specific depending on the clicked element, you can populate event data from `evt` that is provided to `toggleState()`.

I've made the toggling of visibility via styles. This is because that in many cases I've dealt with there has been some kind of visual effect for toggling the element.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This wont work because I couldn't click the Toucheables behind it anymore.

Comment: @Damathryx did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Kind of an old question already but it's the first result, so here it goes:

We'll fill the background of our relevant container with an invisible element that takes up the whole screen, like so:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onBlur}>
    <View style={{width, height, position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0}} />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

This is my full modal that accepts children (styled to center them):

```
import {Dimensions, View, TouchableWithoutFeedback} from 'react-native';

const ModalFloating = ({children, onBlur = ()=>{} }) => {
    const [{width, height}, setSize] = useState({width: 0, height: 0});

    return (
        <View style={[styles.wrapper, {width, height}]} onLayout={() => setSize(Dimensions.get('window'))}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onBlur}>
                <View style={{width, height, position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0}} />
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        {children}
    </View>
    )
};`
```