# TouchableOpacity swallow touch event and never pass

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I'm trying to make both `onPress` to happened `TouchableOpacity`, but the second one is the only one that fires:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.warn('first button')}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.warn('second button')}>
    <Text>
      PRESS ME
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

How can I make both of them fire?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can do this - that's not how the touch responder system in React Native works. Maybe you could describe why you are trying to do this and what you are trying to achieve, and there might be a better solution?

Comment: If your use case is that simple why don't you merge your 2 `TouchableOpacity` to a single one?

Answer (score -1):

You can fire both of them simply using the 'ref' concept and calling the props onPress.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
  AlertIOS.alert('firstbutton')
  } 
  ref={component => this.myFirstTouchable = component}
>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
        {
        AlertIOS.alert('second')
        this.myFirstTouchable.props.onPress()
        }
    }>
        <Text>
          PRESS ME
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer NOT to use `ref`, it's not one of the best practices and should be use it only incase there are no other solutions

Comment: You actually ask for something you need to avoid in an app (2 Touchable elements at the same place doing 2 different actions).

Comment: ref is not a "bad practices"! Accessing a ref via this.refs.myString is, not accessing the element via the ref callback. There is a lof of librairies using the ref callback. Even RN itself... (take a look at the UIExplorer exemple) 

From React docs : 
__Using the ref callback just to set a property on the class is a common pattern for accessing DOM elements. If you are currently using this.refs.myRefName to access refs, we recommend using this pattern instead.__