# React Native: Hover image onPress

Tags: android, ios, image, react-native, react-redux

Hi Guys i dont know how to create a hover if the User Press on a Image. 
Please help me see my code below.

```
const { name } = this.props.category;
const { url } = this.props.category;

return (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.onRowPress.bind(this)}>
    <View>
      <CardSection>
          <View style={styles.imageViewStyle}>
              <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>{name}</Text>
          </View>
          <Image source={{uri: url }} style={styles.imageStyle}/>
      </CardSection>
    </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);
```

I have a List of Items with Images and name in my database 
and i try to realize that case: 
if user Press on Image show White Box (Hover) with some opacity and show 2 different Button "Add new Thred" and "Show all Threds"

thank u

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081732/can-touch-out-side-a-view-component-be-detected-in-react-native

Answer (score 1):

Use `React Native Modal` to create the **hovering white box**.

Understand what is a `modal` first example from below tutorial

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_modal.htm

**On Image** `onPress` **make** **modal visible**

Apply `styles` in a proper manner so that it would look like the **dialogue box** you want like you mentioned in question.

Use `position absolute` that will be more suitable, example below.

```
   render() {
            return (
                <Modal
                    hardwareAccelerated
                    animationType={'slide'}
                    supportedOrientations={['portrait']}
                    visible={this.state.isVisible}
                    onRequestClose={() => {
                        this.props.onClosePress();
                    }}
                 >
                  <View
                    elevation={5}
                    style={styles.modalBackground}
                   >

                   </View>
                </Modal>
            );
        }


const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
   modalBackground: {
     backgroundColor: 'white',
     position: 'absolute',
     overflow: 'hidden',
     top: 50,
     right: 50,
     left: 50,
     bottom: 50
   }
})
```

Adjust the `margins` according to your needs.