# Close modal when clicked outside of <Modal> in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

I am making an application in react native. Here I am able to open Modal at a click and also able to close the modal when clicked inside of the Modal. But I also want to close the Modal when clicked outside of it.

Below is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Modal, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Alert } from 'react-native';


function Main({ navigation }) {
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

    return (
        {/* This is not working */}
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { setModalVisible(!modalVisible); }}>
            <View>

                {/* MODAL FOR LANGUAGE */}

                <Modal animationType="slide" transparent={true} visible={modalVisible}>
                    <View>
                        <Text>Select Language</Text>
                    </View>

                    {/* Close modal*/}
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { setModalVisible(!modalVisible); }} >
                        <Text>English</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { setModalVisible(!modalVisible); }} >
                        <Text>Hindi</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </Modal>
                <View>

                   {/* Open modal*/}
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { setModalVisible(true); }} >
                        <Text>Language</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}
```

I hope from the comments you can see that I am opening modal when clicked on `<Text>Language</Text>` , and I am able to close modal when clicked on `<Text>English</Text>` and `<Text>Hindi</Text>`, which is inside the modal.

To close the modal when clicked on outside of modal I used `<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { setModalVisible(!modalVisible); }}>` , but this is not working.

**NOTE**: I have intentionally removed all the styling part so that my code here looks clean and that I can make it clear about what I want.

Comment: Possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081732/can-touch-out-side-a-view-component-be-detected-in-react-native/60478348#60478348

Comment: @SagarShakya It's way to complicated, and I think that answer is for web, not for native

Comment: Did you try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41731898/14757539

Answer (score 1):

I believe when modal is visible it covers all the screen and you do not have access to the underlaying components. Did you try to create a backdrop inside  modal?

Here's an example:

```
return (
  <View>
    {/* MODAL FOR LANGUAGE */}

    <View>
      {/* Open modal*/}
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          this.setModalVisible(true);
        }}
      >
        <Text>Language</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

    <Modal animationType="slide" transparent={true} visible={modalVisible}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.5}
        style={{
          height: '100%',
          backgroundColor: '#e74655',
          opacity: 0.5
        }}
        onPress={() => {
          this.setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: '80%',
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#000',
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 0,
          backgroundColor: '#fff'
        }}
      >
        <View>
          <Text>Select Language</Text>
        </View>

        {/* Close modal*/}
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
          }}
        >
          <Text>English</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
          }}
        >
          <Text>Hindi</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  </View>
)
```

Which produces this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaLsY.png), where the red area is touchable and closes the modal when you press on it